# Pointer magic to cast a vector3 to a vector2 c++

Tags: c++, casting, macros, box2d

I have two types of vector representations and I'm battling how I should convert between the two. My solution is to use this macro:

```
#define danger_cast(type_to_cast_to, what_to_cast) *(type_to_cast_to*)&(what_to_cast)
```

Which is used like so:

```
Vec3 old_vector(3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
b2Vec2 vector = danger_cast(b2Vec2, old_vector);
```

This works since both vector types have their member variables in the same order. That is:

```
float x,y,z;
```

and

```
float x,y;
```

respectively.

Would you consider doing this? Would it be more proper to make some sort of utility functions that would convert between the two types, can you come up with another more proper solution to this problem?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` instead of macro, but strict aliasing rule is broken anyway.

Comment: First off, don’t use a macro when you could use a function instead. Second, what Jarod said. And third, don’t do this. Copy instead. It’s probably as efficient anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the funny thing is that OP is still copying! :D

Comment: In addition to the problems pointed out by Jarod42, casting objects is also quite dangerous with virtual functions or multiple inheritance. Since you copy anyway (when you assign), just write a function that constructs a new b2Vec2 from a Vec3.

Comment: I could make the macro into `#define danger_cast(type_to_cast_to, what_to_cast) *reinterpret_cast<type_to_cast_to*>(&(what_to_cast))`. The macro is both about readability, searchability and laziness. Do you mean that it would be better to explicitly write that cast whenever using it, @Jarod42? What function would you suggest to do this cast, @KonradRudolph? Template or just one for each type conversion required?

Comment: Why do need to convert between the two? Do you want to write functions that work with both types? Can you modify the vector types?

Comment: Its a matter of being stuck with having a closed source game engine, without a physics engine, using its own vector types and our need to interface with box2d for physics. So the game engine already has a bunch of features built on its own vector type, such as models, cameras and animations.

Comment: If you have access to `b2Vec2`, create a constructor which takes `Vec3`, else if you have access to `Vec3` create `operator b2Vec2() const` else create regular function `b2Vec2 Makeb2Vec2FromVec3(constVec3&)`.

Comment: I would also think about creating a wrapper around the closed source engine that translates from your vector type to their type to keep the other code clean and not have conversions all over your code. And do not use macros. There is not much need for them in C++ anymore in normal code.

Comment: I am not sure if that is a good idea, but lets assume that `Vec3` is your code and b2Vec2 is the foreign code. You could define your class similar to `struct Vec3 {b2Vec2 xy; float z;}`, and then add a conversion operator `operator b2Vec2 const&() const {return xy;}` to save some copying. This would allow to cast a `Vec*` to a `b2Vec*` if it is a standard layout type, which may be usefull to interface with the foreign code.

Comment: Good suggestion, @Jarod42. We can probably access box2d stuff on our server to add some functionality. I'll also look into making a wrapper around it @Jens!

Comment: Both classes are foreign code in that sense. We can't alter the Vec3, since it's closed source, but could potentially tweak the header of b2Vec2. Would I have to recompile box2d if I added a constructor taking a Vec3 in the header?